# Interatomic distances between hydrogens in allene

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure

[image: Diagram of allene with interatomic distances marked]

If $d_1$ and $d_2$ are the interatomic distances between the pairs of hydrogens shown above, what is the relation between $d_1$ and $d_2$?

I think that $d_1$ and $d_2$ might be equal since the terminal hydrogen atoms are perpendicular to each other.

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Answer (score 3):

Propadiene is an [allene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allene) which has $D_\mathrm{2d}$ symmetry. This dictates that the distances between the hydrogen atoms at the opposite terminal carbons are the same. In mathematical terms:

$$d(\ce{H^a-H^c}) = d(\ce{H^a-H^d}) = d(\ce{H^b-H^c}) = d(\ce{H^b-H^d})$$

Below shows the resymmetrised ($R\gg0.99$) geometry on the GFN2-xTB semi-empirical level of theory. In faint colours the $C_2$ axis are displayed.

[image: geometry of propadiene with highlighted H-H distances]